# Avoid round off for specific column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I have performed operation like:

```
df: 
      ColA      ColB       ColC 
      2.7E-16   7.9E-08    1.3E-16
      5.4E-19   2.2E-02    4.5E-18
```

I dont have the Confidence column to be rounded.

The output looks like:

```
  ColA      ColB       ColC     Confidence %
  2.7E-16   7.9E-08    1.3E-16   1.0
  5.4E-19   2.2E-02    4.5E-18   1.0
```

I want the utput to look like:

```
  ColA      ColB       ColC     Confidence %
  2.7E-16   7.9E-08    1.3E-16   99.999990
  5.4E-19   2.2E-02    4.5E-18   99.9999000
```

Code:

```
pd.set_option("display.precision", 15)


pval_dataframe['Confidence %'] = pval_dataframe.min(axis=1).apply(lambda x: 1- x )
```

Comment: Are you looking to add a new row (as the question title describes) or are you trying to change the percent in col `confidence`

Comment: Sorry! I have changed the question title

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
a = ["2.7E-16","5.4E-19"]
b = ["7.9E-08","2.2E-02"]
c = ["1.3E-16","4.5E-18"]    
pval_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data={"ColA":a,"ColB":b,"ColC":c})

pval_dataframe = pval_dataframe.astype(float)

pd.set_option("display.precision", 15)
```

What I have tried is :

```
pval_dataframe['Confidence %'] = pval_dataframe.min(axis=1).apply(lambda x : format(float(1-x),'.30g'))
```

Read the documentation of [format](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) function

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you can use `Decimal`

```
from decimal import Decimal

df['Confidence %'] = df.min(1).apply(lambda x: 1 - Decimal(x))


        ColA            ColB            ColC             Confidence %
0   2.700000e-16    7.900000e-08    1.300000e-16    0.9999999999999998700000000000
1   5.400000e-19    2.200000e-02    4.500000e-18    0.9999999999999999994600000000
```